In a @DataJpaTest, why does an SQL query still get executed even when the entity is already stored in the first-level cache?
The test class inherits from the Fixture class and shares its fields.
In the Fixture class, a method annotated with @BeforeEach saves entities before the tests in the test class are executed.
Additionally, since the test class is transactional, the entities saved in the @BeforeEach method are expected to be stored in the first-level cache.
Fixture Class
@SuppressWarnings("NonAsciiCharacters")
public class MemberQueryRepositoryFixture {

    @Autowired
    protected MemberJpaRepository memberRepository;

    protected Member 멤버;
    protected Member 저장된_멤버;
    private final FixtureMonkey fixtureMonkey = FixtureMonkeyConfig.entityMonkey();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        멤버 = fixtureMonkey.giveMeBuilder(Member.class)
                          .setNotNull("oauthId")
                          .setNotNull("name")
                          .setNotNull("email")
                          .set("oauthPlatform", OAuthProvider.GOOGLE)
                          .setNotNull("signatureColor")
                          .setNotNull("nickname")
                          .setNull("googleCredentials")
                          .setNull("pushKey")
                          .sample();

        저장된_멤버 = fixtureMonkey.giveMeBuilder(Member.class)
                              .setNotNull("oauthId")
                              .setNotNull("email")
                              .set("oauthPlatform", OAuthProvider.GOOGLE)
                              .setNotNull("name")
                              .setNotNull("signatureColor")
                              .setNotNull("nickname")
                              .setNull("googleCredentials")
                              .setNull("pushKey")
                              .sample();
        memberRepository.save(저장된_멤버);
    }
}

Test Class
@DataJpaTest
@Import({QueryDslConfig.class, MemberQueryRepository.class})
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
@SuppressWarnings("NonAsciiCharacters")
class MemberQueryRepositoryTest extends MemberQueryRepositoryFixture {

    @Autowired
    private MemberQueryRepository memberQueryRepository;

    @Test
    void 멤버_이메일로_멤버_조회() {
        //when
        final Optional<Member> actual = memberQueryRepository.findMemberByEmail(저장된_멤버.getEmail());

        //then
        assertSoftly(softly -> {
            softly.assertThat(actual.isPresent()).isTrue();
            softly.assertThat(actual).contains(저장된_멤버);
        });
    }

I expected that when an entity is stored in the first-level cache, it would be retrieved directly from the cache without executing an SQL query. However, contrary to my expectation, the following SQL query was executed.
2024-08-28T00:04:06.711+09:00 DEBUG 45181 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select m1_0.id,m1_0.birth,m1_0.create_date,m1_0.email,m1_0.gender,g1_0.id,g1_0.access_token,g1_0.channel_expiration,g1_0.channel_id,g1_0.channel_token,g1_0.refresh_token,g1_0.resource_id,g1_0.resource_state,g1_0.resource_uri,g1_0.user_id,m1_0.last_modified_date,m1_0.name,m1_0.nickname,m1_0.oauth_id,m1_0.oauth_platform,m1_0.profession,m1_0.profile_img,m1_0.push_key_id,m1_0.role,m1_0.signature_color from member m1_0 left join google_credentials g1_0 on g1_0.id=m1_0.google_credentials_id where m1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select m1_0.id,m1_0.birth,m1_0.create_date,m1_0.email,m1_0.gender,g1_0.id,g1_0.access_token,g1_0.channel_expiration,g1_0.channel_id,g1_0.channel_token,g1_0.refresh_token,g1_0.resource_id,g1_0.resource_state,g1_0.resource_uri,g1_0.user_id,m1_0.last_modified_date,m1_0.name,m1_0.nickname,m1_0.oauth_id,m1_0.oauth_platform,m1_0.profession,m1_0.profile_img,m1_0.push_key_id,m1_0.role,m1_0.signature_color from member m1_0 left join google_credentials g1_0 on g1_0.id=m1_0.google_credentials_id where m1_0.id=?
2024-08-28T00:04:06.931+09:00 DEBUG 45181 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into member (birth,create_date,email,gender,google_credentials_id,last_modified_date,name,nickname,oauth_id,oauth_platform,profession,profile_img,push_key_id,role,signature_color,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into member (birth,create_date,email,gender,google_credentials_id,last_modified_date,name,nickname,oauth_id,oauth_platform,profession,profile_img,push_key_id,role,signature_color,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2024-08-28T00:04:06.941+09:00 DEBUG 45181 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select m1_0.id,m1_0.birth,m1_0.create_date,m1_0.email,m1_0.gender,m1_0.google_credentials_id,m1_0.last_modified_date,m1_0.name,m1_0.nickname,m1_0.oauth_id,m1_0.oauth_platform,m1_0.profession,m1_0.profile_img,m1_0.push_key_id,m1_0.role,m1_0.signature_color from member m1_0 where m1_0.oauth_platform=? and m1_0.email=? and m1_0.name=?
Hibernate: select m1_0.id,m1_0.birth,m1_0.create_date,m1_0.email,m1_0.gender,m1_0.google_credentials_id,m1_0.last_modified_date,m1_0.name,m1_0.nickname,m1_0.oauth_id,m1_0.oauth_platform,m1_0.profession,m1_0.profile_img,m1_0.push_key_id,m1_0.role,m1_0.signature_color from member m1_0 where m1_0.oauth_platform=? and m1_0.email=? and m1_0.name=?

I'm curious why a select query is executed even though the entity is stored in the first-level cache.
Also, looking at the queries, select, insert, and then another select are executed. I'm wondering why the select query runs twice, even though there was only one retrieval in the test.

Hibernate is unable to run JPQL queries against persistence context (L1 cache), instead of that it flushes dirty entities to DB and queries DB.

Could you provide any documents or code that might help with understanding? I still don't quite get it.

Can you please post the Member class code, in particular how is defined the id field and if there are Lombok annotations like @Data? Also check the logs: the select clause that is shown, is related to a filtering policy that is not only related to email field, but also to name and `oauth_platform".
